# Ion-slide-box how to shown-pager on device?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a ion-slide-box and pager is shown. When I open my app on browser it is working good, but when I export it to the device, The "dot's" are missing. Any solution?

In some old devices it is showing square instead of dot's but in new devices its showing nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the ionicons web font from your apps package. Open up the dev tools to debug your application using chrome / safari and check that it's being downloaded correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ion-slide-box show-pager="true">
<!--list of element-->
</ion-slide-box>
```

try this in your code !

Comment: This does not appear to be a complete answer to the question; Please explain how your code is used to solve the problem.